# Unable to modify modify TeX-command-list and setup pdf previewing in emacs and mactex

Tags: emacs, mactex

I am trying to setup a pdf preview command in emacs. Stumbling around the web I found the following which I thought I would try.

```lisp
(eval-after-load "tex"
  '(add-to-list 'TeX-command-list
  '("pdfview" "open -a TeXShop %s.pdf" 'TeX-run-command nil t) t))
```

Unfortunately, the command does not show up in the command list when I type <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd>. *Is there something fundamentally different I need to do?*

Also, I am not running auctex, just using the vanilla latex-mode.

Comment: Could you please provide a link for where you found those configuration lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be running AUCTeX—that's where `TeX-command-list` is defined.  The builtin `tex-mode.el` uses `tex-compile-commands` instead (though the format is different).  But you really need to be running AUCTeX because it's *much* better.  It's worth it just for preview-latex.

For the vanilla latex mode the comparable code would be (untested):

```lisp
(eval-after-load "tex-mode"
  '(add-to-list 'tex-compile-commands
                '("open -a TeXShop %r.pdf") t))
```